# One __construct in multi Controller (Codeigniter 3)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have many controllers and need one __construct.
Do not want to copy every time if I've change one. Just want to change it all with one save.

Example if my __construct is similar this:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->data['url'] = base_url();
    // Another Codes
}
```

How can I use it in my another controllers?

Comment: Constructors are inherited. Just extend your class and construct objects of the child class(es). If you provide a constructor in the child class though the parent constructor will have to be called explicitly.

Comment: suppose this construct is made in admin_controller ... and use this constructor use user controller so, class user controller EXTENDS admin_controller